# Applying integration by parts repeatedly to get a Taylor series

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, taylor-expansion

Evaluate the following integral
$$L(x)=\lim_{n \to ∞}\int_0^x t^ne^t \,dt$$

Intuitively, it seems like when $0<x<1$, the integral should converge to 0 since $t^n$ converges to 0 and it is multiplied by the finite term of $e^t$.

But, when I applied integration by parts repeatedly to the given integral, I got this series;

$$L(x)=x^ne^x-n(x^{n-1}e^x-\int_0^x t^{n-2}e^t \,dt)$$
$$L(x)=x^ne^x-nx^{n-1}e^x+(-1)^2n(n-1)x^{n-2}e^x...(-1)^{n-1}n!\int_0^x te^t \,dt$$
$$L(x)=(-1)^{n-1}n!+e^x\left[\sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^{n-k}\dfrac{n!}{k!}x^{k}\right]$$

which is evidently, the series expansion of $(-1)^{n}n!(e^{-x}-1)$ in disguise.
Hence, the limit becomes;
$$L(x)=\lim_{n \to ∞}(-1)^{n}n!(e^{-x}-1) $$

which does not seem to converge to 0 conditionally when $0<x<1$, it only does so when $x=0$. So, where did I go wrong in this problem? Or was my intuition incorrect? If so, can someone please explain why?

Comment: $$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \left( {( - 1)^n n!{\rm e}^x \sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {\frac{{( - 1)^k }}{{k!}}x^k } } \right) = \left( {\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } ( - 1)^n n!} \right){\rm e}^x \left( {\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {\frac{{( - 1)^k }}{{k!}}x^k } } \right)
$$ holds if the individual limits both exist, which is not the case here.

Comment: But, the second limit does hold when 0<x<1 because it's within the radius of convergence of the Taylor series, right?

Comment: It holds for all $x$, but the issue is that the limit of the first factor does not exist. In general, $\lim (a_n b_n)=\lim a_n \lim b_n$ if both $\lim a_n$ and $\lim b_n$ exist.

Comment: I know that if we break a limit into two limits which exist, the original limit exists and if we break a limit into two limits both of which do not exist, then the original limit may or may not exist. But if we break a limit into two limits out of which one exists and the other does not exist, does that not imply that the original limit does not exist?

Comment: Think about $a_n=\cos(n)$, $b_n=\frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: oh right, one makes an oscillatory limit while the other converges to 0, while the whole limit does exist. I get it now, thanks!

Comment: Note that in the integration by parts procedure you are missing the constant term $
( - 1)^{n + 1} n!$. You can check this by noting that $L(0)=0$. Then the Lagrange remainder formula for the Taylor series shows that $L(x)=
\theta _n(x) \frac{{x^{n + 1} {\rm e}^x }}{{n + 1}}$ with a suitable $0<\theta _n(x)<1$.

Comment: That makes sense, I think I missed the very last integration of e^x.

Comment: Wait what, that's where the constant term is from?

Comment: Yes, in the end you have $$( - 1)^n n!\int_0^x {{\rm e}^t {\rm d}t}  = ( - 1)^n n!({\rm e}^x  - 1).
$$

Comment: @Gary, I made all the corrections in my problem........can you now help explain why this expression should tend to 0 for all x between [0,1]?

Comment: You cannot just pass the limit in the second component to get the Taylor series of $\mathrm{e}^{-x}$ but not doing it in the first term.

Comment: So I'm correct up till the second last step. How do I proceed from there, instead of applying the limit on second component?

Comment: Write the partial sum of the Maclaurin series of $\mathrm{e}^{-x}$ as a difference between $\mathrm{e}^{-x}$ and the $(n+1)$th Lagrange remainder term.

Comment: That will be $\frac{e^cx^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$ for some c in [0,x]. Oh, okay just worked it out, it ultimately boils down to finding the limit of $x^{n+1}/n+1$. Thanks for being so patient Gary, I understand now!

Comment: Note that by setting $t=xs$ and using the mean value theorem for integration $$
\int_0^x {t^n {\rm e}^t {\rm d}t}  = x^{n + 1} {\rm e}^x \int_0^1 {s^n {\rm e}^{ - x(1 - s)} {\rm d}s}  = x^{n + 1} {\rm e}^x \theta _n (x)\int_0^1 {s^n {\rm d}s}  = \frac{{x^{n + 1} {\rm e}^x }}{{n + 1}}\theta _n (x)
$$ for some $0< \theta _n (x)<1$.